# Can tornado set_secure_cookie expires timestamp?

Tags: timestamp, tornado

I check tornado set_secure_cookie function code, it can set cookie in expires_days, but I want to know whether it can be set expires in timestamp form.

For example:
    self.set_secure_cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", expires=timestamp)

```
timestamp is value like 1432527031.
```

Could somebody answer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the [docs and code](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.set_secure_cookie), it doesn't look like you can set a timestamp value there.

Comment: yearh, set_secure_cookie will invoke set_cookie, and set_cookie has argument expires, it may be set a timestamp value there.

Comment: I had tried it. It works if we set_secure_cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", expires=datetime), but not timestamp.

Comment: I just tested this and it works with `expires=timestamp`. What kind of error were you seeing?

Comment: @BenDarnell I did not test expires=timestamp case, I tested expires=utcdatetime.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not well-documented, but the `expires` parameter may be in any format accepted by [tornado.httputil.format_timestamp](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.format_timestamp), which includes both seconds-since-epoch timestamps and datetime objects.